# How to use .NET CancellationTokens with Fetch AbortController API

Tags: asp.net-core, fetch, abortcontroller

I'm trying to use CancellationTokens to cancel long running requests if the Fetch request I do in my front end is cancelled/aborted. I'm using [Fetch AbortController / AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) to cancel requests that take too long to run.

I've created a minimal web API demonstrating my issue:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/test", async (CancellationToken ct) =>
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
    }
    return "complete";
});

app.Run();
```

In the front-end, I do a fetch request like so:

```
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5429/test', { signal: AbortSignal.timeout(2500) });
```

In my browser console I can see that the request is actually aborted after 2500ms:
[image: Fetch request being cancelled]
However, the `CancellationToken` in the backend is **never updated to cancel the request**, and thus keeps running indefinitely.

Am I misunderstanding how `CancellationTokens` work, or am I missing a part of the implementation?

Comment: it depends on what your browser did. there's no communication channel to indicate the request was aborted: https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-minimal-apis/

Comment: @DanielA.White that makes sense. The linked article states that the injected `CancellationToken` is the `HttpContext.RequestAborted` cancellation token, so I was hoping that I could re-use this cancellation token to detect that the request was cancelled. Do you have any suggestions on how I can make the cancelled request actually request cancellation of the running task? An alternative solution I found was creating my own `CancellationTokenSource` with a `millisecondsDelay`, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it.. I would like to let the front end decide what timeouts to use.

Comment: You can periodic check if client is still connected and if not, cancel. When fetch is aborted, it should drop the connection.